# RxJs - Simple way to get a specific value from an observable ( filtered array )

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Here is an array:

```
usersBirthData = [
  {Name: "Adam", year: "2020", userBirth: "adam-2020"},
  {Name: "Adam", year: "2019", userBirth: "adam-2019"},
  {Name: "Adam", year: "2018", userBirth: "adam-2018"}
];
```

and I would like to filter it on a given 'year' and extract the corresponding 'userbirth' value, so I defined  a variable to pass the filtering value (manually for now for simplicity), and another one to get the resulting value:

```
selectedYear = '2019';    // with recent versions of Angular type becomes obvious once a value
userBirth = '';           // is assigned, so no need to define it here.
```

and then defined an Observable to return a filtered array using 'of' operator, like so:

```
  getUserBirth() {
    return  of(this.usersBirthData).pipe(
      map(res => res.filter(ub => ub.year === this.selectedYear))
    );
  }
```

and then subscribed to it to get the required value, like so:

```
this.userBirth = this.getUserBirth().subscribe(res => res.map(x => x.userBirth));
```

but for some reason got the following error:

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'string'.

So what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: this.getUserBirth().subscribe(res => this.userBirth = res.userBirth):

Comment: With this I get error: Property 'userBirth' does not exist on type '{ Name: string; Year: string; userBirth: string; }[]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter` will retrun an `array`.

1. first solution is just use `.find` method in place of `.filter` if occurrence is once.

   ```
   getUserBirth() {

     return  of(this.usersBirthData).pipe(
       map(res => res.find(ub => ub.year === this.selectedYear))  // using find
     );

   }


   this.getUserBirth().subscribe(res =>{ 

     this.userBirth = res.userBirth;

   });
   ```

**OR**

2. With `.filter` you can do following changes,

   ```
     this.getUserBirth().subscribe(res =>{

        this.userBirth = res[0].userBirth;  // res[0] since you are using .filter method which returns an array always.

    });
   ```

Comment: With .filter I get Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Yes because you are using `'.filter`. so you are dealing with array only. any `map` in turn returns you array.

Answer (score 1):

The `subscribe()` method returns an Observable, that is something that is called everytime a new value comes in.

You should do the assignment inside the subscribe callback, like so:

```
this.getUserBirth().subscribe(res => this.userBirth = res.userBirth);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.userBirth = this.getUserBirth().subscribe(res => res.map(x => x.userBirth));
```

The type of `this.userBirth` is `string`.
But `.subscribe` will return a `Subscription` type value which is not assignable to a string.

You can do this instead:

```
userBirth: string[];
...
this.getUserBirth().subscribe(res => {
    this.userBirth = res.map(x => x.userBirth);
});
```

Comment: so `userBirth` type is `string[]` in my answer

Comment: Yes, this can be an answer too, maybe considered as a workaround, I was defining userBirth as a string not an array of strings because I wanted to return a unique value, but at the end your answer is also helpful and ends into a working solution.